# ROS 2 Bag Record with Topic Remapping

Tags: ros2, rosbag-record, rosbag2

Hello dear ROS Developers,

I am trying to record a ros2 bag in my humble, i am having the /scan_filtered topic, now i want to record the /scan_filtered topic in a bag, but it should store inside the bag in the name of /scan topic. In ros1 I'll achieve this using remapping. But in ros2 i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot remap on `record` side in ROS2 version of rosbag. But you can do that on `play` side: `ros2 bag play /path/to/bag --remap scan_filtered:=scan`